# Prevent voice input on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, input, voice

I have html `input[type=text]` element.
I want user **NOT TO** use voice input / voice typing (actually I need to prevent voice input provided by Android/iOS on-screen keyboard) on my `input` element or entire `document` at all.

// Tryed hard to find any answers, but it looks like no one else got the problem.
// I've already put other preventive attribs on the `input` so it looks exactly:

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
```

And yes, I understand this feature is up to mobile's keyboard, not browser.
Anyway, please suggest any workarounds.

**Update**: The interface exactly needs user to type words *with their hands*. There are no accessibility issues due to interface's purpose.

Answer (score 5):

This is simply not possible because of sandboxing. It's also an awful idea because it ruins accessibility.

You could try using Javascript to only listen to keydown events, but this depends on the voice-to-text program not emulating key presses, and also removes the ability to copy-and-paste.

You could have an on-screen keyboard which requires users to click the buttons instead of using their own keyboard, But you won't be able to override the native keyboard without accessing the phone's API, which is usually only exposed to native apps.

You're really playing with fire in terms of UX with either of those solutions, though. Is there any reason you can't allow voice-to-text, or are you trying to reduce errors?

Comment: Yes, there **IS** a reason why I want it to ignore any 3rd-party input behavior (be it voice-input, copy-paste, drag-n-drop or just spell-checking auto-correction, etc). Believe, I **need** to get input ONLY via typing. It is set by the **purpose** of the web app.